# Configure Visual Studio 2013 .sln to use Local IIS (Not Express)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013

I keep getting errors saying that my IIS express has stopped working and I would like to configure my project to use IIS instead of IIS Express. When I run it I can see that is says IISExpress, as seen in the picture below. I tried to research a possible solution and saw that some people were able to go to properties and change the server to use Local IIS but I don't think I have that option available in the same place because I am using a different type of project. How would I be able to configure my project to use Local IIS (and stop receiving these "IIS Express Server has stopped working" error messages).

Thank you

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Project]

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust the project properties to point to IIS.

[image]

See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(WebApplicationProjects.WebPropertyPage);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

Comment: Usually I can get there by right clicking and going to properties but when I do that with this project it pops up the Property Pages window as seen in the screenshot above. How can I either (a) access the page that you have posted or (b) change to Local IIS another way.

Comment: @BrettKB Be sure you're accessing it via the Project in Solution Explorer, not the Solution. The Solution will bring up those properties in your screenshot.