# iisexpress 10 stopped working after installing iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, iis-express

I installed iis so I could do some local testing with a phone, but afterwards, iisexpress stopped working, the browser (IE) just spinning until the "This page cannot be displayed." message.  I've rebooted, reinstalled iisexpress 10, but no change.  I created a new web app, but also didn't work.  I'm stuck.  The website does work under iis.  Windows 10, VS2015.

Thanks.

-John

Comment: What site bindings were used when you use IIS Express? Since installing IIS increases the possibility of binding conflicts, it is not surprising to see one of them fails to work.

Comment: The only configuration I know of for IIS Express via VS is the 5 digit port number, which not 80.

Comment: use Jexus Manager to add the solution file as a new IIS Express server, then you can easily see far too many settings. http://jexusmanager.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use IIS? Just define in project properties IIS like web server, and your URL will look like http://localhost/YourApplicationName
Now I'm Using Windows Server 2016 Technical Prevew for testing and developing Web Applications, so I'm Using IIS as my web server works fine.

Comment: Is it the case that you need to run VS2015 as administrator for this to work?

And does the website need to be configured in the iis manager?

The only way I could get it to work was to set the website up without a host name, use http://localhost in Visual Studio, and run Visual Studio as administrator.

Are there decent instructions somewhere that describe the process?  It would be nice if it was just turn key like iisexpress was before.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071010/configure-visual-studio-2013-sln-to-use-local-iis-not-express this may help, is you dont want to use IIS you have to uninstall it, but if you like IIS you can configure it first of all you need add IIS_IUSER user to permisions.