# In visual Studio 2015 IIS express works but Local IIS does not

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am working on a project that needs to be worked on Local IIS. I have used only IIS express but recently for any web project if I use Local IIS then it does not work. Please guide me through this -

[image]

And if browsed through inetmgr - [image]

Comment: You need to create the virtual directory in IIS.  This looks like a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071010/configure-visual-studio-2013-sln-to-use-local-iis-not-express?rq=1

Comment: @KevinRaffay The virtual directory is created in IIS. The second screenshot is when browsed from IIS (INETMGR) . I did checked the link you posted and its not similar to mine. For hime IIS express was not working and for me local IIS is not working. IIS Express is working perfectly.